# Setting default table order in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with a table and I am trying to figure out is there a way to set the default order to ASC when the page loads?

```
class Orders extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        data: [
          {orders: 'Vanilla', date: '03/15/1990'}, 
          {orders: 'Chocolate', date: '03/15/1989'}, 
        ],
        sortingOrder: 'ASC'
      };

      this.sortBy.bind(this);
    }

    renderTableData() {
        return this.state.data.map((data, index) => {
            const{orders, date} = data
            return (
                <tr key={index}>
                   <td>{orders}</td> 
                   <td>{date}</td>
                </tr>
            )
        })
    }

    sortBy(sortedKey) {
        const data = this.state.data;
        let sortingOrder = this.state.sortingOrder; 
        if(sortingOrder === 'ASC') {
            sortingOrder = 'DESC'; 
            data.sort((a,b) => b[sortedKey].localeCompare(a[sortedKey]))
        }
        else {
            sortingOrder = 'ASC'; 
            data.sort((a,b) => a[sortedKey].localeCompare(b[sortedKey]))
        }
        this.setState({data, sortingOrder })
    }

    render() { 

      return (
        <table id="orders">
        <thead> 
          <tr className="header">
            <th>Order</th>
            <th onClick={() => this.sortBy('date')}>Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead> 
          <tbody>
            {this.renderTableData()}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      );

    }
  }
```

I tried calling this.sortBy() in my render method first, but that gave me an error about too many calls. Any ideas?

Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: please post the error

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://codesandbox.io/s/59607711-so-soritng-default-by-asc-prcz2

Answer (score 0):

you can do on componentDidMount for default

```
componentDidMount(){
 this.sortBy('ASC');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the comopnentDidMount method

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

```
componentDidMount(){
 this.sortBy('date');
}
```